# Adding a way to view assignments due within the next seven days in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building a basic student planner application using Ruby on Rails and I am trying to implement a way for a student to see which assignments are due within the next seven days. I would like to use a scope method, something like due_soon that can be called within a view.

Currently when I run my code I'm getting an ArgumentError in Assignments#index and it's telling me that the comparison of Date with :due_date failed

My Assignments model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
  # accepts_nested_attributes_for :course

  validates :course_id, :student_id, :due_date, :title, presence: true
  scope :due_soon, -> { where(Date.current + 7.days >= :due_date) }

  def course_attributes=(attributes)
    binding.pry
    if attributes[:course_name].blank?
      self.course = Course.find_by(id: params[:course_id])
    else
      self.course = Course.find_or_create_by(attributes)
      self.course
    end
  end
end
```

In my view:

```
<h3>Due Soon</h3>
    <% Assignment.due_soon.each do |assignment| %>
      <% if assignment.course %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= assignment.title %></td>
          <td><%= assignment.course.course_name %></td>
          <td><%= assignment.due_date %></td>
          <td><%= link_to "View/Edit Assignment", student_assignment_path(@student, assignment) %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated as I try and continue to familiarize myself with rails! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having here is related to your usage of `where`:

> Assignment.where(Date.current + 7.days >= :due_date)

Is not valid for ActiveRecord's `where` method.

What you need is to either use ActiveRecord's lib to generate SQL (1), or write the SQL yourself (2):

```
# (1) Use ActiveRecord combined with a Ruby Range
Assignment.where(due_date: Date.current..7.days.from_now)

# (2) Assignment.where('due_date between ? and ?', Date.current, 7.days.from_now)
```

Comment: Went with your suggestion of using a range and it worked perfectly, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error there.

One way is...

```
scope :due_soon, -> { where('due_date =< ?', Date.current + 7.days) }
```

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods/scope